# Android - Exception at startup (for some users)

Tags: android, exception, startup, androidx

I recently moved from v4 support/compat libraries to androidx, and while it seems to be working fine (at least on any device/emulator I've run it on), some users seem to be experiencing a crash. I can't *guarantee* that it's due to the androidx migration, but it's suspicious timing.

Here's the stack trace of the crash (`FileActivity.java` is my launch activity):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2473)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2541)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5597)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:984)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:779)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:813)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:508)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:415)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
  at com.me.myapp.FileActivity.onCreate (FileActivity.java:104)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6010)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1122)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2426)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2541)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5597)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:984)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:779)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:575)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
    ... 21 more
```

and the scene of the crime:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);
    ...
```

So as I understand it, it's failing to find a class when inflating the `activity_file` layout, which is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:divider="@color/divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                android:longClickable="true"
                android:minHeight="64dp"
                android:paddingBottom="72sp"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:stackFromBottom="false"/>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_documents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/no_documents_found"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:maxWidth="24dp"
            android:maxHeight="24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_plus" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/file_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And, for good measure, the referenced `toolbar` and `drawer_header` layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_background"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/documents"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawer_wallpaper"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And (as requested) `file_menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".FileActivity">
    <group android:id="@+id/documents">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_documents"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/blank"
            android:title="@string/documents"/>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/source">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_googledrive"
            android:icon="@drawable/googledrive"
            android:title="@string/googledrive"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_dropbox"
            android:icon="@drawable/dropbox"
            android:title="@string/dropbox"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_onedrive"
            android:icon="@drawable/onedrive"
            android:title="@string/onedrive"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_device"
            android:icon="@drawable/device"
            android:title="@string/device_storage"/>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/settings">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/gear"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_upgrade"
            android:icon="@drawable/upgrade"
            android:title="@string/action_upgrade_now"/>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/recover">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_recover"
            android:icon="@drawable/blank"
            android:title="@string/recover"/>
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/help"
        android:title="@string/action_help"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/blank"
        android:title="@string/action_about"/>
</menu>
```

Is there something here that I'm missing that would cause a crash only on some devices? Like, possibly, earlier versions of Android?

(Making this possibly trickier is the fact that some other users seem to get a startup crash where the report includes *only* the `java.lang.RuntimeException`, and no further "caused by" stack trace. I don't know if that's related, but first things first.)

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your work and it works fine on my computer. So maybe another layout file is causing the problem. When you migrated to AndroidX, did you let Android Studio do it for you? In Android studio follow `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` should do it for you. *However* you have to manually migrate your xml layout files from using any older dependency. So, go through your Gradle file and for each androidx dependency you see, check that your xml files aren't using the "support" version. For example, you shouldn't see any "android.support." in any of your xml layout files.

Comment: Thanks. I did use the built-in refactoring, and thought I audited the XML files carefully. I'll go through them again. (But if something's referencing the wrong class, for instance, shouldn't it crash for everyone, including me?)

Comment: If you could recreate the issue yourself, then you could share the exact device type and steps to recreate with us.